# Analytical or semi-analytical formula for the CDF of the finite-dimensional distribution of a Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be a standard BM, is there an analytical or semi-analytical formula for the CDF of $(B_{t_1}, B_{t_2},\cdots, B_{t_n})$? Here $t_1<\cdots<t_n$, and by CDF I mean the probability
$$\Bbb P(B_{t_1}<x_1,\cdots,B_{t_n}<x_n).$$

Low dimensionality cases seem simple e.g. $n=2$ or $3$ because we can somehow "invert" the covariance between the few $B_{t_i}$s and get an integration region under *standard* multivariate normal distribution. We can get the region right because dimensionality is low and our intuition works. But this no longer works for, say, $n\ge 4$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Well we know that the vector $B_{t_i}$ are multivariate normals with means zero and a covariance matrix we can explicitly write. Let $\Sigma$ be the covariance matrix, and try looking at $\Sigma^{-1/2} B$, where $B$ is the vector of the $B_{t_i}$. It's easy to show that $\Sigma^{-1/2} B$ is a standard multivariate normal. Thus for any set $C$, we have $P(B\in C) = P(\Sigma^{-1/2} B \in \Sigma^{-1/2}C)$, which you can write down in terms of the standard multivariate normal pdf.

Comment: By the way, if the above approach doesn't get you want you want, then you could also try iterative conditioning and using the independence of the increments (i.e. condition on $B_{t_1}$, simplify, condition on $B_{t_2}$, simplify, etc.)

Comment: @Kurt that's exactly what I meant by "inverting the covariance". However, it's not manageable for $n\ge4$, because $\Sigma^{-1/2}C$ is difficult to figure out.

Comment: @Kurt as for your second suggestion, I haven't tried it, but I also doubt it would be tractable when the dimensionality builds up.